# Unable to debug & run default.aspx

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I tried to F5 (debug & run) the program but was unable to do so.
Visual Studio 2017 hang at dos screen showing header: Sep02Project\Sep03Project\Bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe.

[Output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZUrh.jpg)

[DOS screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy8fu.jpg)

what other stuffs do I need to check?

Comment: the links is broken

Comment: how to heck and where can I fix it ?

Comment: I cant help on this. because the links are bad.